# Compute the determinant (similar to Vandermonde)

Tags: determinant

Compute the determinant of the matrix follows,
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&\cdots&n\\1^2&2^2&\cdots&n^2\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1^n&2^n&\cdots&n^n\end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scale the columns by $\frac11, \frac12, \ldots\frac1n$, and what you have left is exactly a Vandermonde determinant times $n!$.

Comment: Is $a_{2n}=2^n$ a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Vandermonde for $x_i=i$ can be also written as 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n+2} (k-1)! $$
there is a special function for that called [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function). In terms of it
$$
G(n+2)
$$